# Adding custom form field arguments

Tags: python, django

I am trying to add custom form field model arguments but am getting the error `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'nginit'`:

my field:

```
self.fields['formdata.name'] = forms.CharField(label = 'Your name', nginit = None, required = True, max_length = 100)
```

my subclass modifier:

```
from django import forms
old_build_field = forms.fields.Field
class build_field(old_build_field):
    def __init__(self, nginit = False, *args, **kwargs):
        super(build_field, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.nginit = nginit

forms.fields.Field = build_field
```

Comment: Hi, how did you solve this problem? Could you please add some code as solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you're trying to monkeypatch the base Field class in the hope that the subclasses like CharField will inherit from the new class. Unfortunately, that's not how it works. All the class inheritance is executed at import time, so CharField will always inherit from the original Field class, not your monkeypatched version.

A slightly better approach would be to monkeypatch the `__init__` method of Field directly, since that is only invoked when the class is instantiated. Even then, though, you'd need to be sure to your monkeypatching is done before the form definition itself: since CharField is instantiated directly at class level in the form, once again that will be done at import time. As long as the modification is done before that in the form module, though, it should work.

There are probably much better ways of doing this, I must say. For example, you could add the nginit parameters to each of the fields directly in the form's own init method.